# Strange error when ran saying outofbounds exception

Tags: java

First part

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class RelativesTester
{
    public static void main( String args[] ) throws IOException
    {


        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("Relatives.dat"));

            int z = in.nextInt();

            for(int x = 0; x<z;x++)
            {
                String n = in.nextLine();
                Relatives a = new Relatives();
                a.setPersonRelative(n);
                System.out.println (a);
            }

    }
}
```

2nd part

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Relatives
{
    private Map<String,Set<String>> map;

    /**
     * Constructs a relatives object with an empty map
     */
    public Relatives()
    {
        map = new TreeMap<String,Set<String>>();
    }

    /**
     * adds a relationship to the map by either adding a relative to the
     * set of an existing key, or creating a new key within the map
     * @param line a string containing the key person and their relative
     */
    public void setPersonRelative(String line)
    {
        String[] personRelative = line.split(" ");
        String person = personRelative[0];
        String relative = personRelative[1];

        if(map.containsKey(person))
        {
            map.get(person).add(relative);
        }
        else
        {
            Set<String> relatives = new TreeSet<String>();
            relatives.add(relative);
            map.put(person,relatives);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the String version of the set containing person's relatives
     * (see last line of sample output)
     * @param person the person whose relative set should be returned as a String
     * @param the string version of person's relative set
     */
    public String getRelatives(String person)
    {
        String s = "";
        s+=(person);
        s+=(" is related to ");

        for(String relative : map.get(person))
        {
            s+=(relative);
            s+=(' ');
        }
            return s;
        }


    /**
     * returns the String version of the entire map listing each key person and all of
     * their relatives
     * (see sample output except last line)
     */
    public String toString()
    {
        String output="";


        return output;
    }
}
```

dat file

```
14
Jim Sally
Fred Alice
Jim Tom
Jim Tammy
Bob John
Dot Fred
Dot Tom
Dot Chuck
Bob Tom
Fred James
Timmy Amanda
Almas Brian
Elton Linh
Dot Jason
Dot
```

I get an error saying outofboounds exception and have no clue why or what that means? I haven't finished toString yet is that the problem or is it some thing else? If it is the toString how can I format it so it looks like this

```
Bob is related to John Tom
Dot is related to Chuck Fred Jason Tom
Elton is related to Linh
```

I can't get it to work

Comment: Which line does the error occur on?  It should say, near the start of the error message.

Comment: I suspect that what's happening is that after you've read that initial integer, your next call to `nextLine` is retrieving the rest of that first line - in other words an empty string.  When you try to split that empty string into a person and a relative, it finds no names, so you get an empty array.  Then you try to find items 0 and 1 in that array, which don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If the file does not have two strings separated by a space then the following code will fail

```
String[] personRelative = line.split(" ");
String person = personRelative[0];
String relative = personRelative[1];
```

Did you try to debug this at all?

Comment: a.setPersonRelative(n);

Comment: & String relative = personRelative[1];

Comment: sorry I do not understand your comments.

Comment: Yes, my answer shows that I understand where the error was.  Do you undertsand my answer?

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted, I can only see one place where you'd get that error.  (It'd be helpful if you posted the exact error as well, as it contains information about where the exception occurred, the line number, stack trace, etc.)

```
String[] personRelative = line.split(" ");
String person = personRelative[0];
String relative = personRelative[1];
```

If `line.split()` returned an array with length 1, attempting to access index 1 would cause an OOB exception.

If you *know* that `split()` should return an array of length 2, then verify it.  For example,

```
String[] personRelative = line.split(" ");
if(personRelative.length != 2){ throw new RuntimeException("Split Error!"); }
String person = personRelative[0];
String relative = personRelative[1];
```

As a side note, I really suggest you read up on some basic java tutorials, [like these](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

The last line of your dat file do not contain any . So, the split method returns an array of size only 1. While reading this line, the following code causes OutOfBoundsException:

```
String[] personRelative = line.split(" ");
String person = personRelative[0];
String relative = personRelative[1];// This line causes ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```